# Animating static images in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyanimate

I'm building a Shiny app that displays various pre-rendered .png and .svg images across multiple tabs, with some of the images being chosen through different types of input. To add some pizzazz, I'd like to add animations to the images that play whenever an image is displayed, either when the tab that it's on is selected or when it is chosen through an input.

I've tried using `shinyjs::show/hide` and `shinyjqui::jqui_effect`, but those functions seem to want to respond to some input, like a button press, rather than playing automatically and repeatedly.

I've managed to put together the code below that uses `shinyanimate` to achieve the desired effect. However, my real app has many more tabs and images, and this method of having every animation react to any changes in the tabs or inputs seems inefficient. Is there a better way of doing this?

(N.B. I'm only using the "bounceInLeft" effect here because it makes the example clear, but I'd like to be able to use other animation effects such as "fadeIn").

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyanimate)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    withAnim(),
    
    tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
        
        # Tab 1 ----
        tabPanel("Tab 1",
                 
                 fluidRow(
                     column(3,
                            
                            imageOutput("tab1_img1")
                            
                            ),
                     
                     column(3,
                            
                            imageOutput("tab1_img2")
                            
                            )
                     )
                 ),
        
       # Tab 2 ----
       tabPanel("Tab 2",
                
                selectInput("img_opts",
                            label = "Select image",
                            choices = c("img2", "img1")
                            ),
                
                imageOutput("tab2_imgs")
                
                )
    )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

    # Tab 1 image 1
    output$tab1_img1 <- renderImage({
        
        list(src = file.path("images/img1.png"), width = "95%")
        
        }, deleteFile = FALSE)
    
    # Tab 1 image 1 animation
    observeEvent(input$tabs,
                 
                 startAnim(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), "tab1_img1", "bounceInLeft")
                 
                 )
    
    # Tab 1 image 2
    output$tab1_img2 <- renderImage({
        
        list(src = file.path("images/img2.png"), width = "95%")
        
        }, deleteFile = FALSE)
    
    # Tab 1 image 2 animation
    observeEvent(input$tabs,
                 
                 startAnim(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), "tab1_img2", "bounceInLeft")
                 
                 )
    
    # Tab 2 images
    output$tab2_imgs <- renderImage({
        
        list(src = file.path(paste0("images/", input$img_opts, ".png")), width = "25%")
        
        }, deleteFile = FALSE)
    
    # Tab 2 animation
    observeEvent(c(input$tabs, input$img_opts),
                 
                 startAnim(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), "tab2_imgs", "bounceInLeft")
                 
                 )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same result with only one observer:

```
tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
            
            # Tab 1 ----
            tabPanel("Tab 1",
                     
                     imageOutput("tab1_img"),
                     value = "tab1_img"
                     
            ),
            
            # Tab 2 ----
            tabPanel("Tab 2",
                     
                     selectInput("img_opts",
                                 label = "Select image",
                                 choices = c("img2", "img1")
                     ),
                     
                     imageOutput("tab2_img"),
                     value = "tab2_img"
                     
            )
)

observeEvent(c(input$tabs, input$img_opts), {
  
  startAnim(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), input$tabs, "bounceInLeft")
  
})
```

## EDIT: using `shinyjqui`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabs",
    # Tab 1 ----
    tabPanel(
      "Tab 1",
      fluidRow(
        column(3,
               imageOutput("tab1_img1")
        ),
        column(3,
               imageOutput("tab1_img2")
        )
      )
    ),
    # Tab 2 ----
    tabPanel(
      "Tab 2",
      selectInput("img_opts",
                  label = "Select image",
                  choices = c("img3", "img4")
      ),
      imageOutput("tab2_imgs")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Tab 1 image 1
  output$tab1_img1 <- renderImage({
    
    list(src = "www/img1.JPG", width = "300")
    
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
  # Tab 1 image 2
  output$tab1_img2 <- renderImage({
    
    list(src = "www/img2.JPG", width = "300")
    
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
  # Tab 2 images
  output$tab2_imgs <- renderImage({
    
    list(src = paste0("www/", input$img_opts, ".JPG"), width = "300")
    
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
  # animate
  observeEvent(list(input$tabs, input$img_opts), {
    jqui_effect(
      paste0("div.tab-pane[data-value=\"", input$tabs, "\"] img"), 
      "shake", 
      options = list(direction = "right", distance = 50, times = 3),
      duration = 1500
    )
  }, ignoreInit = FALSE)
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

## EDIT: better solution

Here is a solution using the JavaScript library **jquery.animatecss** and the CSS library **animate.css**, which is the library used by **shinyanimate**. The app below requires an internet connection to include these libraries (see `tags$head`); it's better to download them (and then to put them in the **www** subfolder).

```
library(shiny)

js <- HTML(
  '$(document).on("shiny:connected", function() {',
  '  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("animate", function(tab) {',
  '    var $tab = $("div.tab-pane[data-value=\\\"" + tab + "\\\"]");',
  '    var $imgs = $tab.find(".shiny-image-output");',
  '    $imgs.animateCSS("bounceInLeft", {duration: 1500});',
  '  });',
  '});'
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.0/animate.compat.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animateCSS/1.2.2/jquery.animatecss.min.js"),
    tags$script(js)
  ),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabs",
    # Tab 1 ----
    tabPanel(
      "Tab 1",
      fluidRow(
        column(3,
               imageOutput("tab1_img1")
        ),
        column(3,
               imageOutput("tab1_img2")
        )
      )
    ),
    # Tab 2 ----
    tabPanel(
      "Tab 2",
      selectInput("img_opts",
                  label = "Select image",
                  choices = c("img3", "img4")
      ),
      imageOutput("tab2_imgs")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Tab 1 image 1
  output$tab1_img1 <- renderImage({
    
    list(src = "www/img1.JPG", width = "300")
    
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
  # Tab 1 image 2
  output$tab1_img2 <- renderImage({
    
    list(src = "www/img2.JPG", width = "300")
    
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
  # Tab 2 images
  output$tab2_imgs <- renderImage({
    
    list(src = paste0("www/", input$img_opts, ".JPG"), width = "300")
    
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
  # animate
  observeEvent(list(input$tabs, input$img_opts), {
    session$sendCustomMessage("animate", input$tabs)
  }, ignoreInit = FALSE)
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is the list of available effects:

```
c(
    "bounce",
    "flash",
    "pulse",
    "rubberBand",
    "shakeX",
    "shakeY",
    "headShake",
    "swing",
    "tada",
    "wobble",
    "jello",
    "heartBeat",
    "backInDown",
    "backInLeft",
    "backInRight",
    "backInUp",
    "backOutDown",
    "backOutLeft",
    "backOutRight",
    "backOutUp",
    "bounceIn",
    "bounceInDown",
    "bounceInLeft",
    "bounceInRight",
    "bounceInUp",
    "bounceOut",
    "bounceOutDown",
    "bounceOutLeft",
    "bounceOutRight",
    "bounceOutUp",
    "fadeIn",
    "fadeInDown",
    "fadeInDownBig",
    "fadeInLeft",
    "fadeInLeftBig",
    "fadeInRight",
    "fadeInRightBig",
    "fadeInUp",
    "fadeInUpBig",
    "fadeInTopLeft",
    "fadeInTopRight",
    "fadeInBottomLeft",
    "fadeInBottomRight",
    "fadeOut",
    "fadeOutDown",
    "fadeOutDownBig",
    "fadeOutLeft",
    "fadeOutLeftBig",
    "fadeOutRight",
    "fadeOutRightBig",
    "fadeOutUp",
    "fadeOutUpBig",
    "fadeOutTopLeft",
    "fadeOutTopRight",
    "fadeOutBottomRight",
    "fadeOutBottomLeft",
    "flip",
    "flipInX",
    "flipInY",
    "flipOutX",
    "flipOutY",
    "lightSpeedInRight",
    "lightSpeedInLeft",
    "lightSpeedOutRight",
    "lightSpeedOutLeft",
    "rotateIn",
    "rotateInDownLeft",
    "rotateInDownRight",
    "rotateInUpLeft",
    "rotateInUpRight",
    "rotateOut",
    "rotateOutDownLeft",
    "rotateOutDownRight",
    "rotateOutUpLeft",
    "rotateOutUpRight",
    "hinge",
    "jackInTheBox",
    "rollIn",
    "rollOut",
    "zoomIn",
    "zoomInDown",
    "zoomInLeft",
    "zoomInRight",
    "zoomInUp",
    "zoomOut",
    "zoomOutDown",
    "zoomOutLeft",
    "zoomOutRight",
    "zoomOutUp",
    "slideInDown",
    "slideInLeft",
    "slideInRight",
    "slideInUp",
    "slideOutDown",
    "slideOutLeft",
    "slideOutRight",
    "slideOutUp"
  )
```

A demo of these effects is available [here](https://animate.style/).

In addition to the `duration` option, the JavaScript function `animateCSS` (used in `js`) also accepts a `delay` option, if you want to delay the animation.

You can improve this solution by allowing to set the desired effect and its options in `session$sendCustomMessage`:

```
js <- HTML(
  '$(document).on("shiny:connected", function() {',
  '  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("animate", function(tab_and_options) {',
  '    var tab = tab_and_options.tab;',
  '    var o = tab_and_options.options;',
  '    var $tab = $("div.tab-pane[data-value=\\\"" + tab + "\\\"]");',
  '    var $imgs = $tab.find(".shiny-image-output");',
  '    $imgs.animateCSS(o.effect, {duration: o.duration, delay: o.delay});',
  '  });',
  '});'
)

    session$sendCustomMessage("animate", list(
      tab = input$tabs,
      options = list(
        effect = "bounceInLeft",
        duration = 1000,
        delay = 100
      )
    ))
```

## EDIT

The images are visible during a very small moment before the animation starts. It seems that this code prevents this issue:

```
js <- HTML(
  '$(document).ready(function() {',
  '  $("a[data-toggle=tab]").on("hide.bs.tab", function(e) {',
  '    var tab = $(e.target).data("value");',
  '    var $tab = $("div.tab-pane[data-value=\\\"" + tab + "\\\"]");',
  '    $tab.find(".shiny-image-output").css("visibility", "hidden");',
  '  });',
  '});',
  '$(document).on("shiny:connected", function() {',
  '  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("animate", function(tab_and_options) {',
  '    var tab = tab_and_options.tab;',
  '    var o = tab_and_options.options;',
  '    var $tab = $("div.tab-pane[data-value=\\\"" + tab + "\\\"]");',
  '    var $imgs = $tab.find(".shiny-image-output");',
  '    $imgs.animateCSS(o.effect, {duration: o.duration, delay: o.delay});',
  '  });',
  '});'
)
```

Comment: This is a great idea! Unfortunately though my real app is a bit more complicated in that it can have multiple image outputs on the same tab, so I don't think this approach will work. I've edited my example and code to show this.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm encountering the same issue that I had with `shinyjqui` before, in that it works well with certain animation effects like "shake", but for entrance and exit animations like "fade" or "drop" you have to use `jqui_show()` or `jqui_hide()`, and these only seem to play once the first time an image is displayed but don't reset to play again when a tab is returned to. Apologies again - perhaps I should have been more clear in my question that I was only using the shake effect as an example, but I'd like to have the option to apply other effects.

Comment: This is brilliant, many thanks for all your help! There's just one last thing though: the animations appear to "stutter" when going back and forth between tabs - the static images are visible for a moment before the animation starts (Example GIF: https://postimg.cc/9DJz2hgJ). Is  there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @Mark_1 You're right. See my third edit. It seems to me it solves this issue, could you confirm? (don't forget to set `delay` to `0`).

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, thank you! From what I understand you've used `var $imgs = $tab.find(".shiny-image-output");'` to identify the images on a particular tab to animate them. What would you use to identify .svg images to animate them (I'm also using `svgPanZoom` in some cases)?

Comment: @Mark_1 `$tab.find(".shiny-image-output")` returns the `div` elements (of the tab) that contain the `imageOutput`s. If you render the SVG images with `imageOutput` (I don't know whether this is possible), then you can use the same code. How do you render the SVG images?

Comment: I'm using `svgPanZoom::svgPanZoomOutput` and `svgPanZoom::renderSvgPanZoom`.

Comment: @Mark_1 So you can do `$tab.find(".svgPanZoom")`.